# how to configure a Sub-domain for email and web service

Tags: email, dns, mailgun

I am developing  a web site and I have it hosted in AWS. To access it I have a domain `domain.org` and I use this domain with a sub-domain for a web service.
So I have

#### CName

`my.domain.org     CNAME      mywebsite.amazonaws.net`

and it works perfectly.

The problem now is that I'm trying to use the same sub-domain as a email service with mailgun. Hence I want to be capable to have something like `example@my.domain.org.` Mailgun tells me to set this configuration:

#### TXT

- `my.domain.org                        TXT      v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all`
- `mailo._domainkey.my.domain.org       TXT      k=rsa; p=SOMEPASSWORDNUMBERS`

#### MX

- `MX    10    mxa.mailgun.org`
- `MX    10    mxb.mailgun.org`

#### CNAME

- `email.my.domain.org    CNAME    mailgun.org`

I have done all this with my DNS provider, but the status of the domain in mailgun is still unverified, specifically the  TXT record `my.domain.org   TXT   v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all` cannot be checked.

I have made some research and found that I should include an A Record with the sub-domain and the IP address that points to the mailserver in mailgun, example:

#### A Record

`my.domain.org   A   nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:`

but my DNS provider **DOES NOT** let me do it, and it says *CNAME record already exists for the entered Host name*

I'm struggling to fix this, but I am still stuck. And I haven't found someone with the same problem on the internet who has solved it already, what I want to know is, if is it possible to use a sub-domain for a web page service using a CName, and as well for a email service?

Comment: Your question is not about a programming problem. It should be better asked on https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: It would help a great deal if you were to let us know exactly what kind of DNS server you are using (e.g., Microsoft on Windows Server, or BIND on Linux).  I just set all of this same sort of configuration up myself, on a BIND server, and it worked great.  Also, you do know that you need to surround the TXT data with quotes?  

As in the following:


    mailo._domainkey.my.domain.org       TXT     "k=rsa;  p=SOMEPASSWORDNUMBERS"

And, remove the period just before the underscore.  And are you using DIG to test for the values being returned correctly by the ZONE record?

Answer (score 0):

Many DNS providers don't allow this, please create a new zone for the particular subdomain and it should work.